# WCF DiscoveryClient returns references to localhost from remote machines

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, service-discovery

I have an app with a self-hosted WCF service.

My WCF service gets published under the URI "net.tcp://localhost:8004/DocumentService". When I run the service on a remote machine and try to discover the service with the new .NET 4 class DiscoveryClient, the found services all have the URI "net.tcp://localhost:8004/DocumentService" too without any information about the actual machine where the service is hosted.

Obviously this is useless if I want to access the service on the remote machine. But I can't find any reference to the actual remote machine (IP address or server name) in the arguments passed to FindProgressChanged.

Is there a way to get the information about the remote machine or do I have to publish my service with the machine name of the remote machine? Or is DiscoveryClient just broken?

I hope this make sense.

Answer (score 4):

I spent a lot of time investigating this problem. Building base addresses in the code was not acceptable for me, as it implies hardcoding transport scheme and port (the latter, of course, can be stored in a separate config section, but then why not just to use the existing section?). I wanted to have an ability to just configure the base address in config as usual. And it turns out that a base address like `<add baseAddress="net.tcp://*:8731/"/>` will perfectly work. I think the same is true for programmatic configuration.

Comment: That's the way, uh huh, etc.  The asterisk resolves for the machine name, which makes it easy, for instance, to write a note to the event log "sup, listening at url: etcetc".